# Kendo Chart sort dir "asc/desc" not sorting

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a data array containing objects with two fields, *date_time* and *sale_quantity*. In my data source I explicitly set *date_time* type to **date**.

When I change the sorting on *date_time* (ASC/DESC), it doesn't change the resulting chart.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        {"date_time": "2018-09-15T11:20:07.85", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-09-15T12:50:33.41", "sale_quantity": 3.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-09-15T12:53:12.85", "sale_quantity": 3.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-09-15T12:54:30.27", "sale_quantity": 2.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-09-15T14:59:48.76", "sale_quantity": 3.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-09-03T11:25:30.16", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-08-30T11:43:48.36", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-08-30T10:50:29.71", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-08-30T10:43:02.60", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-08-30T10:20:57.38", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-08-29T15:28:45.01", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-08-29T11:22:40.04", "sale_quantity": 1.000},
        {"date_time": "2018-08-28T10:05:00.28", "sale_quantity": 1.000}
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                date_time: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    },
    sort: {
        field: "date_time",
        dir: "asc" // DOESN'T SEEM TO AFFECT RESULTING CHART
    }
});

$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    title: { 
        text: "Past 6 Weeks Sales" 
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        labels: {
            dateFormats: {
                weeks: "Week dd/MM"
            }
        },
        baseUnit: "weeks"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column",
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            background: "transparent"
        }
    },
    series: [{
        field: "sale_quantity",
        categoryField: "date_time",
        aggregate: "sum"
    }]
});
```

I have set up the exact same data source and used it with a grid, and sorting works fine. I can't figure out why it works with the grid and not with the chart.

Here are the two fiddles: [Chart](https://dojo.telerik.com/AsizayoZ), [Grid](https://dojo.telerik.com/iRuhATas)

Comment: Try to parse the format from datetime to to Date

Comment: @CarlosMartins I think I did what you suggested and it still doesn't work. See https://dojo.telerik.com/AsizayoZ/7